# How to define the numbering of specific sections in a report

Tags: numbering, report

I am writing lecture notes referring to specific chapters and sections in the textbook chapters and sections.

I use multiple textbooks, so Chapters 1 and 2 of my lecture notes may be from Textbook X, but Chapter 3 of the lecture notes is Chapter 5 in Textbook Y. Similarly for sections. I simply want the section numbering in my lectures to reflect the true section numbers of the respective parts in the textbooks. I put a note at the beginning of every chapter/section to identify the current textbook.

So my question is: how can I re-number specific chapters/sections in a report personally?

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? Also, are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: `\documentclass{report}` and I might want to use `hyperref` later. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a complete implementation that allows you to specify the `\chapter` and section numbering at your own discretion. It works with/without [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref):

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{regexpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\@sect}{the#1}{fixed@seccntformat}{}{}% Insert fixed reference in ToC
\xpatchcmd*{\@sect}{\relax\@svsec}{\relax\fixed@seccntformat\quad}{}{}% Insert fixed reference in heading
\xpatchcmd{\l@chapter}{1.5em}{3.5em}{}{}% Lengthen space for ToC number entry
\newcommand{\fixchapters}{%
  \let\old@chapter\chapter%
  \renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{\xdef\thechapter{##1}% Store chapter #
    \old@chapter}% Old chapter
}
\let\old@section\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\xdef\fixed@seccntformat{#1}% Store section #
  \old@section}% Old section
\let\old@subsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{\xdef\fixed@seccntformat{#1}% Store subsection #
  \old@subsection}% Old subsection
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\fixchapters

\chapter{A.1.B}[Here's a chapter]{A chapter}
\section{3.4}{A section}
\section{1.2}{Another section}
\chapter{1718}{Another chapter}
\section{5}{Yet another section}
\section{8.8}*{Also a section}

\end{document}
```

The idea is different for `\chapter`, but similar for all sectioning commands. For sections, the number is stored in `\fixed@seccntformat` and patched in the section setting macro `\@sect`. For `\chapter`s, the counter printing macro `\thechapter` is updated with the required number.

The reason for supplying `\fixchapters` is that elements of the `\frontmatter` use the starred variant of `\chapter` which are embedded inside macros like `\tableofcontents` and the `\listof`-clan. Of course, a better interface can be adopted, if needed.

Some considerations:

- The interface requires you to supply a mandatory argument as the first argument to all sectioning macros. So you will use `\section{<number>}[<ToC>]{<title>}` *always*. Similar for `\chapter{<number>}[<ToC>]{<title>}`.
- Depending on the chapter/section number length, you might have to update the `\l@chapter` and/or `\l@<section>` macros to give you more space in the ToC. You'll notice, in my example above, that I've increased the regular `1.5em` chapter `\numberline` width to `3.5em`.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I want, although I am not able to compile it yet because of the package you are using. I need to download the file and try then will come back. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit foggy about the implementation you're looking for.  Here's an idea, but I might be missing the point:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lecture}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_my_lecture_book_title_tl
\tl_new:N \l_my_lecture_author_tl
\newcounter{lecturenumber}
\keys_define:nn{ my_lectures }
    {
        chapter . code:n = { \setcounter{chapter}{\number\numexpr#1\relax}},
        section . code:n = { \setcounter{section}{\number\numexpr#1-1\relax}},
        book    . tl_set:N = \l_my_lecture_book_title_tl,
        author  . tl_set:N = \l_my_lecture_author_tl
    }
\NewDocumentCommand{\mylecture}{ om }
    {
        \setcounter{lecturenumber}{\thechapter}
        \keys_set:nn { my_lectures } { #1 }
        \section[#2]{#2\hspace*{\fill}\newline
                 {\small \tl_use:N \l_my_lecture_book_title_tl
                  \hspace*{\fill}
                (\tl_use:N \l_my_lecture_author_tl)}}
        \setcounter{chapter}{\thelecturenumber}
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Modeling Random Times}
\mylecture[chapter=8,
           section=5,
           book={Stochastic Differential Equations},
           author={Bernt \O{}ksendal},
          ]{What's a Random Time Change}

\lipsum[1-3]

\mylecture[chapter=24,
           section=2,
           book={Statistics},
           author={Freedman, Pisani, Purves}
          ]{Modeling Random Events}

\lipsum[4-5]


\chapter{Testing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are several issues, some of which might be:

- A table of index will have slightly confusing numbering going on.  But you might not care about this.  If you do, please elaborate how you want that handled.
- The `\section` command is called with an optional argument solely because I thought you might want a table of contents.

Comment: The is a very neat approach.

Comment: This is very neat and may benefit me well later. But I would also need to rename chapters randomly, not just sections. Thank you very much.