# Setting chapter numbering to alphabetic in one part only

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering, memoir

I need to have the chapter numbering of a specific *part* in my document be alphabetic instead of numeric. How is this accomplished?

MWE playground:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,final]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother  

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\part{First part}

\chapter{First numbered chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Second numbered chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\part{Second part}

% Set chapternum to Alpha here -- how?

\chapter{Alpha chapter A}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Alpha chapter B}
\lipsum[1]

% Reset chapternum to numeric -- how?

\part{Third part}

\chapter{Numbered again from 1}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117091/how-to-define-the-numbering-of-specific-sections-in-a-report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redefine \thechapter:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,final]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\part{First part}

\chapter{First numbered chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Second numbered chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\part{Second part}

% Set chapternum to Alpha here -- how?
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
\chapter{Alpha chapter A}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Alpha chapter B}
\lipsum[1]

% Reset chapternum to numeric -- how?

\part{Third part}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
\chapter{Numbered again from 1}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```